# Android Firebase a value is returning null from Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to make an android app which a user needs to sign-in. For database I am using Firebase's Realtime Database. I made the sign-up and password reset stuff but I am stuck on making the user log-in. I have a database which looks like this:[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFaov.png)

The problem is the password is returning null so when I try to compare it, it just breaks the app.

My current code is:

```
loginButton = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final String username2 = username.getText().toString();
        final String password2 = password.getText().toString();
        final DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String username1 = userSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
                    String password1 = dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue(String.class);
                    if(username1 == null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(loginPage.this, "username1 NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    if(password1 == null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(loginPage.this, "password1 NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    if(username1.equals(username2) & password1.equals(password2)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(loginPage.this, oyunSec.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(loginPage.this, "Incorrect username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });

    }
});
```

I've tried everything that I can from the internet but nothing seem to have an effect. My Realtime Database rules are set to true to both read and write. Any help I can get I appreciate it really much.

Comment: Database location: United States (us-central1)

Comment: I dont know about FRD, but sounds strange getting username from userSnapshot and the password from dataSnapshot

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: I am pretty new to android (just started 2 days ago) so I don't really know the best ways to handle errors. Now it works as I want it to. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the

```
String password1 = dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue(String.class);
```

line. I changed dataSnapshot to userSnapshot and it worked.